# Select2 - multiple inputs with select 2 shares the same options when one of them is selected - BUGG

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4, ui-select2

I am facing a strange problem with the Select2 library. I have added a few select html elements with different options specified for each tag. Each select is decorated with:

```
<select id="selectClient">
                    <option selected disabled="true">Client</option>
                        @foreach (var client in Model.Clients)
                        {
                            <option>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => client.ClientDisplayName)</option>
                        }
                </select>
<select name="SelectedProduct" id="selectProduct">
                    <option selected disabled="true">Produkt</option>
                        @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
                        {
                            <option>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => product.ProductDisplayName)</option>
                        }
                </select>

jQuery('#selectClient').select2({
        placeholder: 'Client',
        allowClear: true
        });
jQuery('#selectProduct').select2({
        placeholder: 'Client',
        allowClear: true
        });
```

Everything works like a charm to the moment when I select an option from the dropdown. When the option from the first select is selected and I move to the second select, then the second select's dropdown contains options from the first select list. Those options are separated in the html file. Did I miss something in the jQuery declaration?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your generated HTML code please ? Because I can't analyze from your razor codes

Check this example it's working fine

[Js Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/wye3az7q/1)

```
<html>
<head>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<select id="selectClient" style="width:200px">
                    <option selected disabled="true">Client</option>
                        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                </select>
<select name="SelectedProduct" style="width:200px" id="selectProduct">
                    <option selected disabled="true">Produkt</option>
                    <option value="1">Option 4</option>
                    <option value="2">Option 5</option>
                    <option value="3">Option 6</option>
                </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Js File

```
$('#selectClient').select2({
            placeholder: 'Client',
            allowClear: true
            });
    $('#selectProduct').select2({
            placeholder: 'Client',
            allowClear: true
            });
```